# Alpine.Js - Multiply Two Input Columns with Dynamic Support

Tags: alpine.js

How can i multiply Qty and Rate in order to get the Total.
How is this possible with Alpine.Js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 
<div x-data="{ qty: 0, rate: 0, total: 0 }">
  <input type="text" x-model.number="qty" name="qty">
  <input type="text" x-model.number="rate" name="rate">
  <input type="text" x-model="qty * rate" name="total">  
</div>  

  
</body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/zaster/pen/zYZVgay

Answer (score 1):

```
<div x-data="{ qty: 0, rate: 0, total: 0}" x-effect="total = qty * rate">
  <input type="text" x-model.number="qty" name="qty">
  <input type="text" x-model.number="rate" name="rate">
  <input type="text" x-model.number="total" name="total">  
</div>
```

This worked!